# canned_fs_config vs fs_config in Android ext4 utils

Tags: android, ext4

When creating the filesystem images Android uses the utility mkuserimg_mke2fs. The utility can be provided a config file with the uid/gid and the permissions. The utility uses the fs_config function when a mountpoint is passed to it and uses the canned_fs_config function when the config file is provided?

1. But what is the difference between canned_fs_config and fs_config?
2. In the function set_perms_and_caps in
   external/e2fsprogrs/contrib/android/perms.c , why is the filename
   cleared when the filename and the mountpoint are the same?